# Can't start a Spring MVC 3.0 app on GAE HR datastore but works on Master/Slave

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC app that works on GAE using the `Master/Slave` datastore.

I created a new app with the `High Replication` datastore configured.

Now the same app won't start on this new environment.

I have no idea what this stacktrace indicates is the reason for the startup failure:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/base/data/home/apps/s~APPID/RESOURCEID/WEB-INF/classes/com/APPNAME/test/Test.class]; nested exception is com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (REQUESTID) started at 2011/09/01 17:04:04.107 UTC and was still executing at 2011/09/01 17:04:54.208 UTC.
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:237)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:202)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:262)
    at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$2.handleRequest(RuntimePb.java:9819)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.handleRequest(RpcUtil.java:445)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:414)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$RpcTask.runInContext(Server.java:579)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:694)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:332)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:324)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (REQUESTID) started at 2011/09/01 17:04:04.107 UTC and was still executing at 2011/09/01 17:04:54.208 UTC.
    at java.lang.String.intern(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.searchMethods(Class.java:2663)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2687)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.Class_$14.run(Class_.java:621)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.Class_$14.run(Class_.java:614)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.Class_.getMembers(Class_.java:614)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.Class_.getDeclaredMethods(Class_.java:253)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotationUtils.java:298)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.visitEnd(AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:213)
    ... 50 more
```

**Anyone have any ideas what the problem might be?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess that you hit GAE during a bad moment and it timed out while reading an XML config file. If that's the case, it has nothing to do with whether the app is M/S or HR, and everything to do with bad timing. Have you got it to run since?

Comment: No it hasn't run since. I've tried it at different times of the day so your theory doesn't seem valid. I've also done the exact same deployment to my M/S app a few times and it works fine there still. My understanding is that M/S is going to be deprecated so I wanted to start this app on the new default HR datastore. It's not a fully public project yet so I can't reveal the appid unfortunately.

Comment: Did something change recently? A few hours after I wrote this everything started working without any changes from me and it's been working fine since.